# Lookup formula isn't always accurate

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Column A & B are examples from a worksheet that is automatically updated from a a historian data base (the data upload changes every time it is refreshed).  Column F & G are examples from a worksheet in the same workbook where I display the conditions in a more organized manner (The very bottom image- I can see exactly what happened on every machine at any minute of the day).  The original has many columns and rows. For some reason, lookup (formula examples is in G1) does not seem to work well for this data format.

In the example below G14 should show a TRUE (highlighted yellow) since B3 had a TRUE (highlighted red) triggered with in that minute (F14).

I would really appreciate any assistance with a better and more accurate formula that would make this work.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `3/15/2016 18:12:00` is not the same as `3/15/2016 18:12:38`. Also, we don't know what the formula is in `B3`, so there is not validation to the claim they should have the same results. Is there a reason you are not using `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: @CharlieRB, the data from column A & B come in from an external data base.  The formatting is simply the words as shown with no back ground formulas.  Column A actually comes in looking like "42444.74653".  I converted it for this example.  I tried vlookup for this example but I was not able to get the formula correct in a way that the results improved.  If you have a vlookup formula that you think will work, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also Lookup or Vlookup will look at the nearest value, it means 3/15/2016 18:13:00 that will give True (of course after making the date with the same Format) The formula in G2 is
=LOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10) and you can drag it down or with Vlookup, in G2:
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$B$10,2)
The result is the same maybe you did not use absolute reference value

Comment: I learned my lesson (hopefully) with date/time formatting issues.  I even double checked that they are in the same format for this example and in my true workbook.  And as the example shows, 18:13:00 is not showing TRUE either.  Lookup works with pulling in a whole lot of other information from the same data base that generates this data.  I added a picture of a completed product.  This example has 18:13 TRUE (red box) showing but now the next one is not showing.

Comment: I tried your example with =LOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10) in G2 and like I said 3/15/2016 18:13:00 gave True

Comment: In the actual data, I have a total of 15 TRUE.  Using the look up formula above, 10 of the TRUE statements are not showing up which means 2/3 is incorrect.  The 2/3 of missed data can change between update/refreshing of the workbook.  Maybe the workbook is over processing and quitting/timing out.  I really hope that is not the case.  I was really hoping there is a different formula that would guarantee everything shows up like it is supposed to, or maybe there is another option I haven't considered (other than updating/correcting them by hand every day) I am open for suggestions.

Comment: I can't use absolute reference value because the original data from the data base changes every day.  One day the list can have 2 rows one day it can have 50.